# C# Program has more than one entry point defined. (CS0017)

Tags: c#, wpf

**Briefing:**

My program says:

*Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with `/main` to specify the type that contains the entry point.*

And it gave me the error code *CS0017*.

**What I've experienced:**

When I change the `Main`-Method to `MainWindow`, the error disappears, but as I said, I'm not *that* experienced to see if this solution is right or wrong.

**Now:**

Yes, I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372342/xunit-test-project-with-only-1-main-method-program-has-more-than-one-entry-poi) (Stack Overflow post about the same issue), but that post didn't help much because it's program specific (I think it's because the xUnit package used in it).

The code below is part of a class named `Rechteck` (yes, I do speak German).

I'm a beginner and I don't know much. And even though I've had a bunch of errors, I never saw something like this. How can I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RechteckWPF
{
    class Programm
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Neues Objekt erstellen
            Rechteck k = new Rechteck();
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
        }

        // Ausgeben
        Console.WriteLine($"Umfang: {k.Umfang}\nFläche: {k.Fläche}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747761/added-a-new-class-to-my-project-and-get-error-say-program-main-has-more-then-o